# Error importing website: "There has been a critical error on your website."

Tags: import

I'm trying to upload my website to a new hosting server.
I've already contacted  them about this issue.

When I try to run the wordpress importer plugin it shows me an error.

[image]

I thought it was because of the versions, but I've tried to export and re-import again, and I have the same issue.
Already tried turn all plugins and run importer, changed some settings on the server and still the same.

**I'm using PHP 7.4.3 and Wordpress 5.4.1**

Comment: What's the error that it has emailed to you? Do you have access to server error logs - is there anything there? It's probably worth checking the email and logs first, but there should be suggestions what to try next on the link it's given you too.

Comment: I think you are approaching the transition of your system with some misconceptions. Either export the whole database and reimport the database on the new host OR set up a new wordpress website and import the posts/custom-post-types/ into the new installation. You can't export a WP website via export of posts.

Comment: I create a link the images https://imgur.com/a/lmRz0UX

I was searching the database and realised that the post is being created with the import file name.